# Converting String to Double/Float loses precision for large numbers in Swift 5

Tags: swift

When i convert "0.0000335651599321165" String value to Double

```
let value = "0.0000335651599321165"
var doubleValue = Double(value)
```

It returns me the value **3.36597214193249e-05**.
How can i get the original number in swift 5.

Comment: Use `Decimal`, not `Double`. Both `Float` and `Double` have smaller precision than you require (not even speaking about decimal to binary precision loss).

Comment: Apart from the imprecision of floating point numbers like Float and Double, you should note that the scientific notation of `"3.36597214193249e-05` is just an aspect of the number's presentation. It's entirely possible for your `Double` to be exactly the value you want, but expressed in this way for readability. If this number is intended for presentation to the user, you should always use `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: main point to get the exact number is to round that number to 6 places at max

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your floating precision you need to use Decimal type and make sure to use its string initializer:

---

```
let value = "0.0000335651599321165"
if let decimal = Decimal(string: value) {
    print(decimal)
}
```

---

This will print:

> 0.0000335651599321165

---

edit/update:

When displaying your value to the user with a fixed number of fraction digits you can use Number Formatter and you can choose a rounding mode as well:

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let number = NumberFormatter()
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    func fractionDigits(min: Int = 6, max: Int = 6, roundingMode: NumberFormatter.RoundingMode = .halfEven) -> String {
        Formatter.number.minimumFractionDigits = min
        Formatter.number.maximumFractionDigits = max
        Formatter.number.roundingMode = roundingMode
        Formatter.number.numberStyle = .decimal
        return Formatter.number.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
let value = "0.0000335651599321165"
if let decimal = Decimal(string: value) {
    print(decimal.fractionDigits())  // "0.000034\n"
}
```